# trouble with canvas.toDataURL and drawimage on Android phone

Tags: android, html, canvas

I want to save an image from canvas to my Android phone. My code is as follows

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 320);
 var strURI=canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
 document.location.href=strURI.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
```

The code works fine on my laptop and I can download the image with it. However, when I try it on my Android phone, nothing happens.

Today, I try to debug my code on my Android phone. I find out that my app crashes when it is  at `var strURI=canvas.toDataURL('image/png')`. That's why I cannot download the image on my phone. Anyone know how to fix the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not hopeful, but have you tried it without the 'image/png'?  You might get a JPEG.  But tbh, it's probably missing a PNG encoder and a JPEG encoder seems even less likely.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it works just fine on my Galaxy Nexus. I just used the code that I made to answer another question here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7QMqX/2/

Does that code work for you?

If it does not create a popup with the image, then you have an android-specific problem, probably version specific.

If it DOES work for you then you probably have a cross-origin problem with your specific image, and it is throwing a security exception on your phone because the image location is not of the same origin as the page.